# Using Windows Task Scheduler for an automatic network firewall authentication

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, windows-11

My college requires students to periodically authenticate for using WiFi and LAN. I am writing a Python script that will automatically do that so that I don't have to manually enter my credentials. The authentication is also separate for WiFi and LAN, and that makes me enter my credentials when I switch between them. So, for the python script, I want to detect when my authentication has expired and my connection is disconnected.

I also don't want the python script to be running constantly in the background and pinging a website as that really isn't optimal and I'll have to run the script every time my PC restarts. I was thinking of using the Windows Task Scheduler to fire the script when it detects that my connection is lost. The trigger event cannot be fixed intervals as the connection can be lost in between the intervals and also when switching between LAN and WiFi.

So, is there any network event that will capture the functionality I want? As Windows gives a notification of "opening the browser to connect" I feel there has to be a background event running.

I tried the NetworkProfile/Operational Event in the Task Scheduler with event id 10001 and 8003. But that just fires when I switch off the WiFi of my PC.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

NetworkProfile/Operational Event with ID 4002 waits for network authentication.